# Which one is the real copy_from_user()?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am reading the Linux kernel code for copy_fom_user, which is architecture dependent and I focus on x86 architectures.

But I got two pieces of implementation for it.

One is [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.3.5/arch/x86/lib/usercopy_32.c#L877) (in arch/x86/lib/usercopy_32.c), while the other is [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.3.5/include/asm-generic/uaccess.h#L243) (in include/asm-generic/uaccess.h).

Which one will be finally compiled into the kernel. I guess the former is the real one, but I am not sure. What is more strange is that the former has the function name _copy_from_user instead of copy_from_user

I always have this kind of confusions when reading the kernel code. For example, due to the conditional compiling, the same function may have multiple implementation and I cannot determine which one will be used in general. Is there any tool that, given a complied kernel and a function of interest, tells you the corresponding binary code, so that you can disassemble it? Or it would be even better if it can tell you the source code that the binary code corresponds to.

Comment: I guess I found the answer: the x86 implementation for copy_from_user is in x86/*/usercopy_32.h: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.3.5/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess_32.h#L202

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, if there is a module present in the architecture-specific subdirectory, that is the one being used.  Otherwise, the generic one is it.

For the modules given, the `.c` is the correct one.  Rarely is there any executable code in a `.h`. I have 2.6.27.8's `uaccess.h` handy:

```
#ifndef _ASM_GENERIC_UACCESS_H_
#define _ASM_GENERIC_UACCESS_H_

/*
 * This macro should be used instead of __get_user() when accessing
 * values at locations that are not known to be aligned.
 */
#define __get_user_unaligned(x, ptr)                                    \
({                                                                      \
        __typeof__ (*(ptr)) __x;                                        \
        __copy_from_user(&__x, (ptr), sizeof(*(ptr))) ? -EFAULT : 0;    \
        (x) = __x;                                                      \
})


/*
 * This macro should be used instead of __put_user() when accessing
 * values at locations that are not known to be aligned.
 */
#define __put_user_unaligned(x, ptr)                                    \
({                                                                      \
        __typeof__ (*(ptr)) __x = (x);                                  \
        __copy_to_user((ptr), &__x, sizeof(*(ptr))) ? -EFAULT : 0;      \
})

#endif /* _ASM_GENERIC_UACCESS_H */
```

Look at that carefully.  These are macro wrappers to call the underlying `__copy_from_user()` and `__copy_to_user()` functions, which are implemented differently on each architecture.

Comment: Thanks, wallyk. I also think so. But can you tell me, when I invoke copy_from_user, how it refers to _copy_from_user (defined in usercopy_32.c)

Comment: I just found the answer in x86/*/uaccess_32.h: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.3.5/arch/x86/include/asm/uaccess_32.h#L202